# XOR Encryption in Assembly, Transmission issue

Tags: assembly, ascii, xor

So I'm transmitting an XOR Encryption between two different computers however I'm having a massive issue where when it transmits a character which ASCII is below 30 then it fails to transmit as these characters below mess with the flow control. I have tried just adding the characters up by 30 to try and avoid this but still failing.

Basiclaly the transmission comes to a complete halt when characters below ASCII 30 are sent.

The code is pretty simple and is as follows-

```
    mov al, character
    xor al, password
    mov character, al
```

Basically a particular combination from variables character and password results in this issue.

Comment: You could just XOR the least significant 4 bits instead of all 8 bits.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Just out of interest, still pretty new to assembly.

Comment: Well you could just mask out the 4 MS bits of your XOR encryption key, e.g. abcdefgh -> 0000efgh and then XOR with that. XOR is very weak encryption anyway, so it hardly matters whether you XOR with 4 bits or 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Characters below 32 are often used as control codes and are not transparently transferred.  I guess you don't use a 8-bit transparent channel.

I would recommend using a 8-bit transparent channel like TCP to transmit.  Just TYPEing will not work.  If that is not an option, use something like base-64 encoding, which maps 3 bytes into 4 characters that are printable and below 128.  Of course, any other encoding will do as well.

BTW: your "encryption" is a extremely weak to the point of non-existance.  Consider using a well-understood algorithm like AES or any other.  There are good and fast libraries available.

Comment: Understood and thank you, Yeah I understand that it's basically not encryption but it's mainly a set of learning projects I'm making myself to learn more and more, I'll move onto what you suggested soon though so thanks very much cxxl!